# free bitmap memory in windows 8 metro style javascript/html5 app

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm writing an app for a client that I've already written in iOS and Android. Before I start I wanted to get some pointers on some issues I expect to encounter. I'm not sure what the memory specs are for the Surface tablet (the main target for the app for now) but the app I wrote loads a lot of external graphics. If I put one of these images in an img/ tag how is the memory handled when the img/ gets removed from the stage (a new PageControl gets loaded). Is there anything explicit I need to do or is this handled automatically (I didn't haven very good exepriences with automatic memory mangement in Android...)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This article describes in detail the memory management in Windows 8 apps:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj651575.aspx